# WPA PEAP connection failure

Tags: network-manager, wpa2

I'm trying to connect my HP laptop from Kububtu 16.04 to a WPA PEAP WiFi connection. It either gets stuck on "configuring interface" or keeps repeatedly asking me for the password.

Now, I have tried all the solutions available on this site. For example, editing the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ssid` to either removing `system-ca-certs` line, or adding the password manually or adding the certificate from `/usr/share/ca-certs/mozilla`. I also disabled "Allow all users to connect to this network". None of the solutions have worked for me. (I always restart NetworkManager before trying another solution).

Also curiously enough after several reboots, once in a while, I'm able to connect to the network, and it keeps getting disconnected, saying wpa supplicant timed out — but I can just click on reconnect and it reconnects immediately. This is until I switch to some other network (the network in question is my university network). Then again I cannot connect to this network on the next day.

Edit: These are the contents of my ssid file (identity and password redacted, obviously)

```
[ipv6]
method=ignore
may-fail=false

[connection]
id=eduroam
uuid=fd3a9c40-1642-49b7-a65f-e07642754f9b
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=eduroam
mode=infrastructure
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=username
ca-cert='/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt'
phase2-auth=mschapv2
password=pass
private-key-password-flags=1
phase2-private-key-password-flags=1

[ipv4]
method=auto
may-fail=false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the configuration file for my Eduroam file (identity deleted). It works at my university and at others (in the UK).

```
[ipv6]
method=auto

[connection]
id=eduroam
uuid=b6ab9322-075c-4ca1-96a3-6c0262c644bb
type=802-11-wireless
timestamp=1461166416

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=eduroam
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=blahblah
seen-bssids=blahblah
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-1x]
eap=ttls;
identity=blahblah
phase2-auth=mschapv2
password-flags=1

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

As you can see, there are several differences. You can try changing the IPv6 configuration method to `auto`, use no certificate, and changing the authentication protocol (eap) to `ttls`.

Comment: Awarded bounty because this seems to be working perfectly (at least for last half an hour). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your description is identical to a problem I experienced with my HP laptop.  Make certain your wireless router has your mac address if it has a mac control  firewall (can block non-listed mac addresses from accessing through the router). Also, you want to be certain that your password entry is flawless (tiniest mistake and your router will not allow you to connect) and you can do so by typing it in a text editor (but do not save it), hold Ctrl (control) and hit "a" (Select all is what that does) while holding the ctrl, then once it is highlighted press (while still holding ctrl) "c" (Copy is what ctrl and c do).  Go back to the passcode entry window any click inside to ensure you're in the entry point and press cntrl "v" (paste is what ctrl v does).  Then your password will be exactly what you typed in the text editor (which you can immediately close once you've entered (pasted) the password into the network password window).  This solved the problem with my HP HDX18 at least. Hope it works for you also.

Respectfully,
David

Answer (score 0):

Have you contacted your university's IT dept?  My wife had a similar issue and we assumed it was an Ubuntu problem at first.  However, I think that the network was actively blocking her connection.  We did not know it at the time, but the particular Wi-Fi network my wife had available is only accessible by the university's computers, or computers that have the university's 'secure' Windows or Mac image installed.  If this is a general wi-fi network that is accessible by students, etc. please disregard.  I thought I would post this though, in case you are an employee trying to access an employee Wi-Fi network.